# Template error when mounting EFS to Elastic Beanstalk EC2 using AWS mount script

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

I am running into

"Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined."

error when trying to deploy tomcat application with

https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config

script to mount the EFS file system to the elastic beanstalk EC2 instance.
I have been trying for a while now to resolve it. Any help is highly appreciated.

The EFS and EC2 are on the same VPC and mounting successfully works when I SSH into the EC2.
Surprisingly I dont see any ERROR logs in the CloudFormation stack either.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out the problem. Its a very stupid mistake, in case you run into this problem here's what i was doing

The discreption says "To use this file to mount a file system that you created outside of AWS Elastic Beanstalk, replace the Ref with the resource ID" in below line

FILE_SYSTEM_ID: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`' so i inferred it should be

FILE_SYSTEM_ID: '`{"<RESOURCE_ID>" : "FileSystem"}`' no this is wrong what they actually mean is do this

FILE_SYSTEM_ID: RESOURCE_ID

I know this was stupid error but in case someone's stuck like me. Hopefully you don't do this mistake.